# PHP - APC Cache - User specific data vs data accessible by all users

Tags: php, caching, apc

I have read a couple of tutorials on several web sites as well as a few questions here on StackOverFlow about the subject and I still couldn't find a clear answer to my question.

I am wondering how APC Cache manages/saves the user-specific data (variables that will be used in the php code, that are user-specific. In other words, data that should not be seen by other users.) and how does it save the publicly available data that all users can see?

I am just trying to understand how it works. I know that APC "saves" or keeps in memory required and included files... but what if those included files have user-specific variables in the code? If let's say in /account/user_profile.php I use several variables like $firstname $lastname $address, etc. will those variables be kept in memory? If, for example, John X is logged in at the time the cache is being updated or saved, then APC will always remember John as $firstname and X as $lastname? If another user goes to the same page, I want him to see its user profile details, not John's.

I know this might have been discussed already, but I need a clear answer, please.

Thank you!

Comment: Matt: Only the code is cached, not the memory. So that's the name of the variables but not their content.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have the false understanding of the APC cache. It's a bytecode-cache, which means it will store the bytecode of a PHP script. This will save the PHP-interpreter the next time to create the bytecode again from the script because it's already there.

> *Note:* Since PHP Version 5.5 it comes with it's own OPCode Cache Core Extension, named [*Opcache*](http://php.net/opcache). Usage of APC for Opcode-Caching is inofficially deprecated. Consult your Sysadmin or Opdesk for detailed information and options, the general principles outlined in this answer still apply regardless of the extensions name.

In normal PHP execution your scripts code will be taken and compiled into byte-code. This byte-code will then be executed by the php processor. It's a common pattern for JIT compilers.

So w/o a bytecode-cache, the bytecode needs to be compiled on each request. With a bytecode-cache, this step needs to be done only once across all requests. Next time the bytecode is already in the cache and can be executed straight-forward.

This is totally unrelated to variable contents, it's just for the code.

Comment: Thanks hakre, that's more clear now. You said that it saves the names of the variables - not the content. What about arrays? If I have an included file, e.g. include_once('code.php') and in code.php I have an array with dozens of values. APC will not remember those values? Is there a way to keep those arrays in memory with APC?

Comment: @Hahkre I believe you can also store data using [apc-store][ http://php.net/manual/en/function.apc-store.php]

Comment: @OZ_: I think [bytecode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bytecode) fits better in the PHP interpreter world, however it's bytecode *and* php-processor-op-code ;)

Comment: @Matt: Arrays are just a variable like any other variable. So it's the same. And each file is compiled and cached, so this is the same for includes.

Comment: The answer is misleading as APC is both a bytecode cache as well as a data cache. In fact, as PHP5.5 now has OpCache, the APCu successor is a data cache only.

Comment: @andig: At the time of writing back in 2011 this was not so far the case. I will leave a link/note to OpCache.

Answer (score 1):

**P.S: I have never used APC(switched to different language before that I really understand the importance of APC), but I think I understand the concept. Please correct me if I am telling a lie somewhere.**

```
> I am wondering how APC Cache manages/saves the user-specific data
> (variables that will be used in the php code, that are user-specific.
> In other words, data that should not be seen by other users.) and how
> does it save the publicly available data that all users can see?
```

You can use [apc_store](http://php.net/manual/en/function.apc-store.php) to store data inside memory, which can be retrieved using [apc-fetch](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.apc-fetch.php). It does not store all your variables inside your program.

```
bool apc_store ( string $key , mixed $var [, int $ttl = 0 ] )
```

> Note: Unlike many other mechanisms in PHP, variables stored using
> apc_store() will persist between requests (until the value is removed
> from the cache).

**Parameters**

*key*

> Store the variable using this name. keys are cache-unique, so storing
> a second value with the same key will overwrite the original value.

From reading the docs I assume that you have to provide unique keys just like you would in memcached/redis. To store data private you would just get the [session_id](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-id.php)(unique per session) and use that as your prefix. You use the `key` to store your data. [This Redis tutorial from Simon Willison](http://simonwillison.net/static/2010/redis-tutorial/) also has a section describing how to use keys which I will quote below:

> Redis is at heart a key-value store, so it makes sense to start by
> talking about keys. Keys should not contain whitespace - versions of
> Redis prior to 1.2 had trouble with this, and even now it's not
> guaranteed that any edge-case bugs have been ironed out. A common
> convention is to use obj-type:id:field, though now that Redis supports
> hashes as values this convention is likely to become less important.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same question.  But the key is this.  APC sees the user not as the end user, i.e. John Smith, but as the application itself.  So when APC says user specific data you can store "user specific data", i.e. information about mywebsite.com in APC about that specific application.  It's not meant for people.  It's meant for one program basically sending variable information to another.